# Display input based on another input value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I am making a react app with form data from JSON.

Implementation wise completed but I am stuck with an issue in making an input box which depend on another.

**Things Tried:**

```
  const config: { [key: string]: any } = {
    defaultHidden: [
      "dose",
      "reason",
      "moreDetails",
      "doseOneDetails",
      "doseTwoDetails"
    ],

    vaccinated: {
      vaccinated: ["reason", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails"],
      not_vaccinated: ["dose", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails"]
    }
  };
```

As the data is retrieved from JSON, I have made a configuration variable to make the defualt hidden and hidden on selection of particular fields.

**Issue:** (Both happen after selecting the dose from select box)

**->** Unable to display the dose one details input box after selecting dose one.

**->** Unable to display the dose two details input box after selecting dose two.

The above issue happens because of `vaccinated: ["reason", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails"],` as it has both the fields under hidden. But I am stuck how to display the respective input field.

**Requirement:**

*Scenario 1:*

User selects `vaccinated` as an option from first select box, then the select box with data as `Dose One` and `Dose Two` appears. Then if user select any of the dose then he need to add details on that respective dose.

*Scenario 1:* (Working Now)

User selects `Not Vaccinated` as an option from first select box, then the `reason` select box will be displayed.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit antd typescript (forked)]

The current configuration takes only one level but how can we handle multi level (*Input depending on other and so on*) like the above scenario?

Kindly help me to get out of this huddle as I am stuck with this for long. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd love to help with this, but there is a lot of code in the CodePen to navigate. If you can provide more of the logic that is working to show and hide the fields in your question, it will make it much easier to help.

Comment: @Willow, What are the more logics I need to provide. Based on my understanding I have provided every code in the question related to the implementation. I am already given my code to show/hide an input field in one level. Requirement is that I need to handle the same in multi level for which I am stuck with.

Comment: @HelloWorld is this what you are looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-typescript-forked-hwhh5

Comment: @SaeedShamloo, Thanks for your help. Consider that if there are some n number of inputs like `reason` input box, then as per this solution we need to include all the n number of input fields to all the properties like `dose_one` and `dose_two`. If we are mentioning in one place only once (like under vaccinated) then it will be fine but keep on repeating the input fields in the multiple places is not the expected as the code will exclude the quality. Hope you understand.

Comment: Why don't you implement your logic in vice versa manner, I mean instead of defining which fields should be hidden, you can define which fields should be visible when you select a value.